# How to do statistical analysis that include 2 levels of repeatedness in R?

Tags: r, mixed-model, repeated-measures

I know this question is a bit general,
I don't have and reproducible code to share, since it's a general question,
I'm trying to understand where to start the investigation about it:
I would like to perform statistical analysis using repeated measures mixed model, the model needs to include 2 levels of repeatedness, How can I do it in R?

Comment: Your question is too broad to provide a specific answer. Could you clarify what you mean with "2 levels of repeatedness"? `lme4` and `nlme` both provide options to include multiple levels of nesting. Three-level models might be what you're looking for, see: https://rpsychologist.com/r-guide-longitudinal-lme-lmer

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be asking about a study design which includes 2 levels of nesting, for example this would be the case in a study that made repeated measurements within many schools, and also repeated measurements within classrooms within the schools. So here you would have classrooms nested within schools. Each classroom "belongs" to a particular school.

This type of design can be modelled with a mixed effects model, or a multilevel model (which in this case would essentially be the same). In R, one of the standard packages to analyse such data is `lme4`.

Note that here we would be dealing with 2 levels of nested (grouping) factors. A different scenario occurs where we have two grouping factor variables that are not nested : that is, they are *crossed*. A typical scenario is where individuals are measured repeatedly doing different tasks, but all individuals perform the same tasks.

More details about the distinction, and how to model these in the `lme4` package can be found here:
[Crossed vs nested random effects: how do they differ and how are they specified correctly in lme4?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/228800/crossed-vs-nested-random-effects-how-do-they-differ-and-how-are-they-specified/228814#228814)